# Regular Expression to add space to each dash at the beginning of string

Tags: c#, regex

```
var input = "---Three dashes a-b-c-d";
```

Regex to get

```
var output = "- - - Three dashes a-b-c-d";
```

and Regex get back to original, added spaces are deleted at the beginning. output => input

Code without Regex input => output

```
var input = "---Three dashes a-b-c-d";
var output = "";
var i = 0;
while (i < input.Length && input[i] == '-')
{
    output += "- ";
    i++;
}
output += input.Substring(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be a negative lookbehind to check that no character before a dash to add a space too is anything but a dash:

```
@"(?<![^-].*)-"
```

- `(?<!` - start of negative lookbehind

  - `[^-]` - any character but `-`
  - `.*` - zero or more of any character
- `)` - end of negative lookbehind
- `-` - a literal `-`

Match globally and substitute with `-`  (dash + space)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6uy1K8/1)

---

Removing the added spaces to get the original back could be done in a similar way:

```
@"(?<![^- ].*)- "
```

Match globally and substitute with `-` (dash).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fBOirM/1)

Answer (score 3):

While @TedLyngmo's solution works, it is rather inefficient with a wild card in the lookbehind pattern.

A more efficient approach would be to use a positive lookbehind pattern to assert that only dashes precede a match:

```
@"(?<=^-+)"
```

And substitute the match with a space.

On regex101, the above regex took 0.2ms to run while @TedLyngmo's took 19.5ms.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6uy1K8/3

Regex (with a trailing space) to remove the added spaces to get back the original:

```
@"(?<=^(?:- )*-) "
```

<sup>Note the space at the end</sup>

And substitute the match with nothing.

On regex101, the above regex took 0.3ms to run while @TedLyngmo's took 28.1ms.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fBOirM/3

Note that the desired behaviors require a regex engine that supports variable-width lookbehind, which C# happens to have. The above regexes are otherwise not portable to platforms that do not have such a support.

Comment: Back to original doesn't work for some reason in .Net 6, unless I am missing something.  No change to output.
input = Regex.Replace(output, @"(?<=^(?:- )*-)", "");

Comment: @MicMit You need the last space too: `@"(?<=^(?:- )*-) "`

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can use the \G anchor to assert the position at the end of the previous match or at the start of the string:

```
\G-
```

In the replacement use `-`  or you can use the full match followed by a space like `$0`

See a [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OOs7Su/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/FKbwX1).

```
var input = "---Three dashes a-b-c-d";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\G-", "- ");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
- - - Three dashes a-b-c-d
```

---

If you want to change it back to the original, you can add matching the space again:

`\G-`

In the replacement use just -

See another [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/22ZoCS/1).

```
var input = "- - - Three dashes a-b-c-d";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\G- ", "-");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
---Three dashes a-b-c-d
```